# Continue to get resource link failures in android after upgrading React Native

Tags: android, react-native

So it started to get unmanageable for me when I go to run `react-native run-android` and I get the error below.

```
> Task :appcenter:processDebugAndroidTestResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':appcenter:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  /Users/danale/Desktop/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/appcenter/android/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugAndroidTestResources/merged.dir/values-v28/values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  /Users/danale/Desktop/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/appcenter/android/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugAndroidTestResources/merged.dir/values-v28/values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  /Users/danale/Desktop/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/appcenter/android/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugAndroidTestResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:957: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  /Users/danale/Desktop/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/appcenter/android/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugAndroidTestResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:958: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.

  Command: /Users/danale/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/ab8b4c002a26280088f841e3556db287/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
          /Users/danale/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar\
          --manifest\
          /Users/danale/Desktop/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/appcenter/android/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debugAndroidTest/processDebugAndroidTestManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          /Users/danale/Desktop/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/appcenter/android/build/intermediates/processed_res/debugAndroidTest/processDebugAndroidTestResources/out/resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_\
          -R\
          @/Users/danale/Desktop/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/appcenter/android/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugAndroidTestResources/resources-list-for-resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          /Users/danale/Desktop/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/appcenter/android/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debugAndroidTest/processDebugAndroidTestResources/r\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          /Users/danale/Desktop/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/appcenter/android/build/intermediates/symbols/androidTest/debug/R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
  Output:  /Users/danale/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar/4c088e56fbd7693aff9e8546648730a6/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

  /Users/danale/Desktop/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/appcenter/android/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugAndroidTestResources/merged.dir/values-v28/values-v28.xml:11: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

  /Users/danale/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/drawee-1.10.0.aar/e4fd679c2bdde73e31136252e1856cdc/res/values/values.xml:3:5-58:857: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

  /Users/danale/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/drawee-1.10.0.aar/e4fd679c2bdde73e31136252e1856cdc/res/values/values.xml:3:5-58:857: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.
  Command: /Users/danale/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx.jar/ab8b4c002a26280088f841e3556db287/aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx/aapt2 link -I\
          /Users/danale/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar\
          --manifest\
          /Users/danale/Desktop/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/appcenter/android/build/intermediates/merged_manifests/debugAndroidTest/processDebugAndroidTestManifest/merged/AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          /Users/danale/Desktop/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/appcenter/android/build/intermediates/processed_res/debugAndroidTest/processDebugAndroidTestResources/out/resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_\
          -R\
          @/Users/danale/Desktop/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/appcenter/android/build/intermediates/incremental/processDebugAndroidTestResources/resources-list-for-resources-debugAndroidTest.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          /Users/danale/Desktop/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/appcenter/android/build/generated/not_namespaced_r_class_sources/debugAndroidTest/processDebugAndroidTestResources/r\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          /Users/danale/Desktop/engage-application.mobile/node_modules/appcenter/android/build/intermediates/symbols/androidTest/debug/R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-osx Daemon #0
```

Okay so perhaps if I clean the build with `./gradlew clean build`, but then I get this error:

```
> Task :app:processDevDebugManifest FAILED
/Users/danale/Desktop/engage-application.mobile/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 Error:
        Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
        is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:13:5-55:19 to override.
```

My `AndroidManifest.xml` file is as it is supposed to be for this upgrade, in fact I removed   `android:allowBackup="false"` because it was complaining about that as well saying:

```
/Users/danale/Desktop/engage-application.mobile/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:21:9-36 Error:
        Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:21:9-36
        is also present at [:react-native-splash-screen] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-35 value=(true).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:13:5-55:19 to override.
```

What is the solution here? I have tried adding the suggestions that it tells me to and it's still not happy.

This is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nfib.engage">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />


    <application

        android:name=".MainApplication"


        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="@string/link_launcher"
                    android:pathPrefix="/auth" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="@string/link_launcher"
                    android:pathPrefix="/events" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="@string/link_launcher"
                    android:pathPrefix="/account/surveys" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My `android/build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
                maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
  gradleVersion = '4.7'
  distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

When I run this: `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies`, I get a successful build but as soon as I go and run `react-native run-android` back to the same error message again.

The file where it's complaining about `dialogCornerRadius` is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat"/>
    <style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
    <style name="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 28+ -->
        <item name="dialogCornerRadius">?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 28+ -->
        <item name="dialogCornerRadius">?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is my latest refactor to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and I am still getting the same errors:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nfib.engage"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />


    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:appComponentFactory="androidx"
        tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="@string/link_launcher"
                    android:pathPrefix="/auth" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="@string/link_launcher"
                    android:pathPrefix="/events" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="@string/link_launcher"
                    android:pathPrefix="/account/surveys" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Check the values.xml file, because this is what the top error suggests has a problem.

Comment: @GauravMall, right, I have checked for that before. It is suggesting certain properties not found and sure enough I did not find them. I am unaware of what the original `values.xml` file is supposed to look like.

Comment: Post the values.xml file for us to see, so we can tell if anything is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `npx jetify` is what resolved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this discussion https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25371

Answer of shreyakupadhyay on 30/07/19 was the right solution in my case.

Comment: Alessandro, when I run `gradle app:dependencies`, none of them output androidx.

Comment: Sorry, the solution I wrote is how to fix without passing to androidx.